# Onload open page in new tab - Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

I have a tricky situation:
I am exiting from PHP using

header('location: nextIndex.php');

and I want that the new page - nextIndex.php - to open in a new tab in Chrome.
How could I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with PHP as its a serverside language.

The easiest way is if you change your location to a page that includes a javascript that opens the new window/tab.

Comment: yes I know I can't. Sorry I was not clear in my posting, it was to present the use case. The only way is certainly javascript but I don't see how to implement a function, run when the page is loaded, to open that very page in a new tab. In fact when the onload handler is executed, inside the page that I want to ... open in a new tab .... Weird.